# refactoring #ifndef __OBJC_GC_ in arc enabled app

Tags: iphone, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm writing an app in an ARC environment, and I'm trying to use a 3rd party library that was written before ARC. I'm using the -fno-objc-arc flags on all the relevant files, so it's compiling, but the project uses #ifndef __OBJC_GC_ blocks to release memory, which is causing memory allocation errors. I'm trying to determine the right solution, and so far I have the following:

1.) find a different library or write my own - this is the only free library of it's kind, so this is obviously not ideal, and I'm new enough that I don't feel comfortable tackling that

2.) remove the #ifndef blocks and cross my fingers - not able to work on the project today, but that's my next plan

3.) refactor the code to be ARC compliant and remove the -fno-objc-arc flags

is #2 likely to work? How hard would #3 be, andwould it actually cause the compiler to define __OBJC_GC_? (there's about 4-5 classes that I'm planning on using, but they're pretty sizeable)

Comment: After figuring out the library itself was creating the allocation erro (not the fact that my compiler settings were wrong) I contacted the guy who wrote it in the first place, and he was nice enough to link me to his newest, rewritten for ARC, version, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the allocation blocks are enclosed into `#ifndef __OBJC_GC_`. 
Note it is `#ifndef` - "if not defined".

So it should work out of the box if the author maintains the non-GC version correctly.
There is no need for you to remove ifdefs or to forge them.

The compiler, even with ARC on, should not define this flag for iOS.
Just make sure the library itself does not set this flag explicitly..

Comment: So is iOS 5 with ARC not a garbage collected environment? I thought it was, but I haven't found a definite answer.

Comment: I did a little more debugging, and it looks like there's an allocation error in the non-arc code I'm using, so this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest considering another option: Turn off ARC for the project.